# lagrangian locus in the quintic as fixed point set of involution

Tags: geometry, complex-geometry

Consider the Fermat quintic
$$X = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^5 = 0 \right\} \subset \mathbb{CP}^4$$
and a map $\sigma: X \to X$ given by $(x_1:x_2:x_3:x_4:x_5)\mapsto (\overline{x}_2:\overline{x}_1:\overline{x}_4:\overline{x}_3:\overline{x}_5).$

Question: is it true that its fixed point locus $L$ is topologically equal to $\mathbb{RP}^3?$

In a naive way, I'd say that the quintic equation cuts out one variable, and the reality condition gives $\mathbb{RP}^3:$ is there a more precise way to see it?

Comment: How did this question arise?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese it arises by studying the (real) topological string on the (real) quintic

Comment: see e.g. 0712.2775 [hep-th]